# Wizard layout form behavior..best practice question

Tags: notification, wizard, mandatory-fields

I have a form on my UI. Some fields in there are mandatory. The user needs to enter these fields and click next to proceed to the next sent of fields..basically a wizard layout.

What is a better experience among these two:

1. When the user tabs out of an unfilled mandatory field, highlight it by turning it red. Disable the Next button until the user enters all the mandatory fields.
2. Let the user click the Next button, and show notification banner at the top telling them to fill in the mandatory fields..while also highlighting the fields by turning them red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validation should happen as soon as possible to allow the user to fix the error. Allowing him to click the next button only to point him to where he missed an input is disrupting his concentration.

From NNGroup:  Ideally, all validation should be inline: that is, as soon as the user has finished filling in a field, an indicator should appear nearby if the field contains an error.

Comment: Thanks Cristian, I agree. I like the words 'Disrupting the concentration'. I may use it :)